# DataRowView Error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, nullreferenceexception

i am trying to make a profile page for my users in my website where they can edit theie profiles.i have used this code but its not working

ASPX page

    
        
    Welcome 
        ,

```
    <br />

Full Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="width:250px; height:25px; border:thin solid #0099FF"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    Company Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="width:250px; height:25px; border:thin solid #0099FF"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<br />
    <br />
```

Web Link

```
    <br />
    <br />

E Mail&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" style="width:250px; height:25px; border:thin solid #0099FF"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
```

Contact No.               
        
        
        
    Location

```
Upload Logo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

    <br />
    <br />
    Company Info&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
```

Business Type

```
    <br />
    <br />

Listings Remaining&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="button" 
        Width="115px" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT fname, cmpny, weblnk, email, cntct, lctn, cdscrptn, bsnstp FROM orgs WHERE (cmpny = @cmpny)"
UpdateCommand="Update [orgs] Set [fname]=@fname,[weblnk]=@weblnk,[email]=@email,[cntct]=@cntct,[lctn]=@lctn,[cdscrptn]=@cdscrptn,[bsnstp]=@bsnstp WHERE [cmpny]=@cmpny">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="cmpny" Type="String" QueryStringField="cmpny" />
</SelectParameters>
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="fname" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="weblnk" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="email" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="cntct" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="lctn" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="cdscrptn" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="bsnstp" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="cmpny" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

ASPX.CS page

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)

 { 
    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView row = dv[0];

    TextBox1.Text = row["fname"].ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = row["cmpny"].ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = row["weblnk"].ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = row["email"].ToString();
    TextBox5.Text = row["cntct"].ToString();
    TextBox6.Text = row["lctn"].ToString();
    TextBox7.Text = row["cdscrptn"].ToString();
    TextBox8.Text = row["bsnstp"].ToString();

}
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    DataRowView row = dv[0];

    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["fname"].DefaultValue = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["cmpny"].DefaultValue = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["weblnk"].DefaultValue = TextBox3.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["email"].DefaultValue = TextBox4.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["cntct"].DefaultValue = TextBox5.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["lctn"].DefaultValue = TextBox6.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["cdscrptn"].DefaultValue = TextBox7.Text.ToString();
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["bsnstp"].DefaultValue = TextBox8.Text.ToString();
    //requisition_id = @requisition_id
    SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["cmpny"].DefaultValue = row["cmpny"].ToString();

    SqlDataSource1.Update();
}
```

i am getting System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: DataRowView row = dv[0];

Comment: Sounds like you have no data.... hence null.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: what do you mean i have no data

Comment: You don't have anything at the 0 index of `dv`.  `dv[0]` is null.  That is what the error is telling you.

Comment: so how can i solve it

Comment: You can't access nothing.  You must access something.  Put something there and then access it.  By the way, there are two lines "DataRowView row = dv[0];" so we're not sure which one is throwing the exception.

Comment: You should step through your code in debug and ensure that your select string has the correct data/format.  Then ensure you are getting results from your `SqlDataSource1`.  If there are no rows to retrieve then that tells you where your problem is.

Comment: the 1st one is throwing the exception

Comment: i have checked my code many times, evertything seems fine. isnt there any other way to do it